# What is the difference between a "native" app and other apps?

Tags: discussion

What is the difference between a "native app" and any other apps? What makes it native? I did not find any answers online.

Comment: [Have you tried Google?](http://www.google.com/search?q=native+apps) [This](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/native-application-native-app) is one of the first results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A native app is one that is installed directly within an `operating system`. A webapp is one that is installed on a web-server and uses a browser to access the functionality on that application.

Examples of Native app:

- Chrome
- Outlook
- Microsoft Word
- Calculator
- Minesweeper
- Tweetdeck
- World of Warcraft
- Angry Birds (if downloaded to a phone)

Examples of Webapps:

- Facebook.com
- Twitter.com
- Gmail.com
- Farmville (this one is a webapp within a webapp, really)
- Google Docs and Microsoft Office Live
- Angry Birds (If played through Chrome's App Store)

Obviously not an exhaustive list, but it's a start.

Comment: Twitter has native apps. Farmville as well.

Comment: yes, Twitter HAS native apps, but Twitter itself isn't a native app.

Comment: I see your point though... i'll update for clarity.